# How to Enable Clean Url in Yii2 Basic in a subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site in the sub-folder of which I domiciled my Yii2 App (Basic Template). Currently the application is configured to display absolute Url, against the friendly PrettyUrl.

I have followed the standard documentation on enabling PrettyUrl, which configuring the urlManager and modifying the .htaccess file.

This actually changes the look of the links, but when I click a link, I get redirected to the Wordpress site in the upper directory, with the Error 404 (Page not Available).

Meanwhile the original .htaccess file in the root directory was:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Following the direction in tutorials for this, I changed it to:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

The Url Manager looks like this :

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
...]
```

It's still not working.

Please what am I not doing well?